# Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, github, open-source

I am trying to deploy an open-source document management system via docker image, so i followed all instructions laid out on google's "Deploying a containerized web application" tutorial. But am getting errors on two stages.

1. When i try to run my container locally using the command

   `docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/hello-app:v1`

   (NOTE: the hello-app is just a sample app used in the tutorial not mine). So the error i keep getting is:

   ```
   [2020-09-14 08:28:42,618: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
      Trying again in 2.00 seconds...
   ```
2. So step is optional when I try to skip it and try to deploy the app to GKE after creating a GKE cluster via this command:

   `kubectl create deployment hello-app --image=gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/hello-app:v1`

   I get this error:

   ```
   error: failed to create deployment: Post "http://localhost:8080/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments?fieldManager=kubectl-create":      
   dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
   ```

I have tried to check my ports in my control panel, turned off XAMP because it was running. then also tried to change other applications that was using similar ports to a different port but nothing worked.

Please help! I'm new to Google Cloud Platform. If anyone has any tutorial or links on how to deploy open-source apps to the cloud precisly Google Cloud Platform (App Engine, GKE etc) Please do share.

Tutorial i followed: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-app

Any sort of help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Seems you application in container is unable to reach the address `127.0.0.1:5672`. If Could you please clarify what is running on your container and the external dependencies? But, by your information, the problem is not in GKE or GCP since you can't run the container locally using docker, try to revise your container and verify the external dependencies.